# Append a 1d array as a new row to a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, append, array-push

I have 2 different arrays with different dimensions  that i need to merge in order to get a result with a specific this structure:

the first:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-03
            [1] => 2017-11-05
            [2] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-23
            [1] => 2017-11-25
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

The second:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2017-12-26
    [1] => 2018-01-30
)
```

The result should be :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2017-11-03
                [1] => 2017-11-05
                [2] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2017-11-23
                [1] => 2017-11-25
                [2] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] =>2017-12-26
                [1] => 2018-01-30
                [2] => 1
            )

    )
```

I tried using array_merge but it does not work because they have not the same dimension. Also I need an element in the second tab ([2] => 1).

Comment: you need to declare default value for missing  element in array

Comment: sorry i don't understand, if you mean  [2] => 1, it's not important i don't use it

Comment: I have posted a solution to this. Works both ways give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$array=Array
(
    0 => Array
    (
        0 => '2017-11-03',
            1 => '2017-11-05',
            2 => '1',
        ),

    1 => Array
(
    0=> '2017-11-23',
            1 => '2017-11-25',
            2 => '1'
        ),


);

$arraySmall=Array
(
    0 => '2017-12-26',
    1 => '2018-01-30'
);


array_push($arraySmall, "1");
array_push($array, $arraySmall);
echo'<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

And the output is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-03
            [1] => 2017-11-05
            [2] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-23
            [1] => 2017-11-25
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-12-26
            [1] => 2018-01-30
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

This way can work even without this line    `array_push($arraySmall, "1");`
You can give it a try. In order to "merge" you need same size but for "push" you don't. So if you commend the line i told you the output will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-03
            [1] => 2017-11-05
            [2] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-23
            [1] => 2017-11-25
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-12-26
            [1] => 2018-01-30
        )

)
```

Comment: thanks does it works it one of the two arrays is empty ?

Comment: strange because when $array is empty it seems there is a problem

Comment: I just tried it. If $array is empty BUT exist (don't delete it just empty it) it will create a new record inside the array which will be the $arraySmall in position 0

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is appending, not merging. Try this:

```
$arraySecond[] = 1;           // This adds [2]=> 1
$arrayFirst[] = $arraySecond; // This adds second array to end of first
```

Answer (score 0):

for your given example:

```
$x = ... // first array [2 dimensions]
$y = ... // second array [1 dimension]

$y = array_merge($y, array_diff($x[0], $y)); // add missing '1' to $y or any other key that are present in elements of $x and have to be added to $y

$x[] = $y; // append the 1-dim array as the new element in $x
```